# How to customize screen resolution with saucelabs (selenium, behat3.0 mink) capabilities

Tags: selenium, behat, mink, saucelabs

This is my behat.yml file :

```
firefox:                  
 suites:  
    firefox:  
      contexts:  
        -FeatureContext
  extensions:  
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      javascript_session: selenium2
      base_url: https://example.com
      selenium2:
        wd_host: username:pwd@ondemand.saucelabs.com/wd/hub
        browser: firefox
        capabilities: {'platform':'OS X 10.10', 'browser':'firefox', 'version':'42.0', "screen-resolution":"1280x1024"}
```

Which is giving error "

[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
  Unrecognized option "screen-resolution" under "testwork.mink.sessions.selenium2.selenium2.capabilities"

I have tried this 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/behat/kApbLIiAkOg, but I am also getting exactly same error.

If I configure SauceLabsDriver then only I will get all (https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension/blob/master/doc/index.rst#sessions) - special flavor of the Selenium2Driver

The above document is suggesting modify your behat.yml profile:

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            sessions:
                my_session:
                    sauce_labs: ~
```

But no idea how to implementing this. Any idea? How to change behat.yml file with saucelabs to use all those customization parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is for behat 2, could you please try [Resizing browser window size with behat2](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/r0cx/resizing-browser-window-size-with-behat2).

```
class FeatureContext extends MinkContext
{
    /**
     * @BeforeScenario
     */
    public function resizeWindow()
    {
        $this->getSession()->resizeWindow(1440, 900, 'current');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This one is working fine with Behat 3.0 too. I have used same setting until now. But now I started using Sauce to run all the test cases with all the set of browsers with different break points (Responsive Web Design). There I want to customize resizing window for each browser/Device combo.

Answer (score 2):

Using resize with `@BeforeScenario` hook can be not optimal.
Another way is to use a scenario step

```
  /**
   * @Given /^I set browser window size to "([^"]*)" x "([^"]*)"$/
   */
  public function iSetBrowserWindowSizeToX($width, $height) {
    $this->getSession()->resizeWindow((int)$width, (int)$height, 'current');
  }
```

And if needed to maximize it back

```
  /**
   * @Given /^I maximize browser window size$/
   */
  public function iSetBrowserWindowSizeToX($width, $height) {
    $this->getSession()->resizeWindow((int)$width, (int)$height, 'current');
  }
```