# How do I fix the browser window size in Behat 3 / Mink?

Tags: behat, google-chrome-headless, mink

I want to run all my Behat/mink tests at a mobile display resolution. What would be really nice is to run all the tests with Chrome in dev tools mode where you can select "iPhone 5/SE" and so on to get a simulation of running on that device.

So, I tried to implement something like this myself by setting the display resolution in FeatureContext.

Here's an [SO question on how to resize browser windows with Behat 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425759/how-to-customize-screen-resolution-with-saucelabs-selenium-behat3-0-mink-capa). And there's [sample code for setting the window resolution in Behat/Mink/Drupal](http://www.devengineering.com/blog/user-insights/resize-or-maximize-browser-window-behatminkdrupal).

Based on these examples, I added the following code to my FeatureContext:

```
  /**
   * @BeforeScenario
   */
  public function resizeWindow()
  {
    $this->getSession()->resizeWindow(100, 500, 'current');
  }
```

However, I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function window() on null
> (Behat\Testwork\Call\Exception\FatalThrowableError)

I also tried:

- Using `BeforeStep` instead of `BeforeScenario` (result: same error)
- Adding a step "I set the resolution to A x B" (result: I can resize the window in tests this way, but when I submit a form in a test, the screen resolution is reset; to fix this, I can add the step to set the resolution after each other step, but that is very inefficient)
- I tried [setting the window size as a chrome switch](https://github.com/minkphp/Mink/issues/525#issuecomment-679510984) in behat.yml, but I couldn't get this to work either (the window size didn't change)

My goal: to force all tests to be executed under Chrome with a fixed window size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this in `@BeforeScenario`:

```
  /**
   * @BeforeScenario
   */
  public function resizeWindow()
  {
    if ($this->getSession()->getDriver() instanceof Selenium2Driver) {
      $this->getMink()->getSession()->start();
      $this->getSession()->resizeWindow(100, 500, 'current');
    }
  }
```

To do this in `@BeforeStep`:

```
  /**
   * @BeforeStep
   */
  public function resizeWindowStep()
  {
    $is_session = $this->getMink()->isSessionStarted();
    if (!$is_session) {
      $this->getMink()->getSession()->start();
    }
    $this->getSession()->resizeWindow(100, 500, 'current');
  }
```